# Invalid href passed to router error after fresh installed create-next-app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After installed nextjs app on my local machine using `create-next-app` I get this error in console `Invalid href passed to router`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

I try to use `to` attribute instead of `href` attribute in `Link` component's but it doesn't help.

Comment: is the url internal? next/link should only be used for internal links.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani the all link's external.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Removing the protocol `http` or `https` from the external url fixes this issue

**example**
`https://stackoverflow.com/` should be `//stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: this is a better solution

Comment: @Yahya I just upgraded to next js 9.5 and it gives me the same error it was working fine in version 9.4.4

Answer (score 12):

You have to set parameter `prefetch={false}`

```
<Link key={index} href={value} prefetch={false}>
                <a target={"_blank"}>
                    {icon}
                </a>
            </Link>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me for "mailto" links.

Comment: I will try it if it work then I accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, nextjs throws that error. Don't use the  component at all if linking to an external source, for external links you can use  tag. In your case we can conditionally render either a plain anchor tag or use the link component if the prop matches an internal route.
For example:

```
Link.indexOf('http') == 0 ? return(<a href={prop}>regular link</a>) : return(<Link>...</Link>)
```

Answer (score 4):

"External URLs, and any links that don't require a route navigation using /pages, don't need to be handled with Link; use the anchor tag for such cases instead."

Given in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Answer (score 1):

The problem was **nextjs** doesn't work with external links that's why console throw's error.

When I remove all external link's and instead add internal link's everything worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, iono why their starter example starts you out with code that has errors. I guess it functions but just has annoying console errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to this document https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/invalid-href-passed.md

Possible Ways to Fix It
Look for any usage of next/link or next/router that is being passed a non-internal href and replace them with either an anchor tag () or window.location.href = YOUR_HREF.