# create-next-app throws the same error on 2 different machines - "Invalid href passed to router:"

Tags: next.js

Just tested this on 2 different computers and I'm getting the same errors every time I create a brand-new project with create-next-app. Didn't used to get this error before. What happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

- for external links, you can use href=""...;
- for router links, use  from 'next/link';
- keep the urls clean, like: //abc.com;

References:

[External href use or router link from 'next/link'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841607/invalid-href-passed-to-router-error-after-fresh-installed-create-next-app)

[Github commit](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/commit/8e4509caf265caeaf434482d3a3c30a974ffe3f3)

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)